# Android's ViewModel and MVVM

Tags: android, mvvm

There is a design pattern called MVVM (Model-View-View Model), in which a **View Model** is used as an abstraction of a View. The View Model supposed to expose streams of data to the View and interact with Model's data.

However there is a [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html) class in Android's framework.

---

**Question:** does Android's [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html) have something to do with the View Model from MVVM pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are different. The ViewModel that Android is referring to is just.

> The ViewModel class is designed to store and manage UI-related data so
>   that the data survives configuration changes such as screen rotations.

The MVVM pattern will require a View, ViewModel and Model. With binding occurring between the View and ViewModel.

The Android ViewModel interacts with the UIController, and is almost just a state hold for UI, rather than following the MVVM pattern.

Comment: I have now found this reference: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/index.html. Looks like Google is trying to give developers better tools for architecture so people get rid of all kinds of 3rd party solutions, like RxJava).

Comment: I mean, it doesn't make sense to add something called ViewModel as an architecture tool, that uses exactly the same name as MVVM's ViewModel and then make it solve different goal.

Comment: I know it doesn't make sense, but Google don't have a great track record of naming things. E.g. "Thing" https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/appindexing/Thing.Builder They literally called something, just "Thing".

Comment: They also have a Presenter that is not a real presenter :)